# Linux vs. Windows execution of lsqcurvefit and importdata in MatLab

Tags: linux, matlab

I recently wrote a program in MatLab which relies heavily on MatLab's 'importdata' function and the 'lsqcurvefit' function from the optimization toolbox. This code takes approximately 15 seconds to execute using MatLab R2011b in Windows. When I transferred the code to a Linux (CentOS) machine, it took approximately 30 minutes.

Using the Profile tool, I determined that the bulk of the additional computation time was spent on the 'importdata' function and the 'lsqcurvefit' function. I cleared all variables in both environments, and I imported identical data files in both environments using 'importdata'. In Linux, this took ~5 seconds, whereas in Windows, this took ~0.1 seconds.

Is there any way to fix this problem? It's absolutely essential that the code operate rapidly in Linux. Both the memory and the processing speed of the Linux machine far exceed that of the Windows machine. After doing some reading, I tried increasing the Java heap memory, but this had no effect.

Comment: Are you running on the same machine dual boot, or are you running on two different computers? I ran into something like this where code on our company's cluster was running 10-20 times slower and it turned out to be because the cluster was built on [AMD processors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33939-poor-matlab-performance-on-amd-based-computer). Try running `bench` from the command line of each platform.

Comment: And is the drive setup on both machines the same? Are you reading the file from local drives on both, or network drives over NFS or SMB? I've run in to a couple pathological cases on older versions of Matlab where doing save/load on network drives was rough (solved by making temp copies on local filesystem) or there was some pathological behavior on NFS exports from a filer that was primarily CIFS, or virus scanner interaction with network filesystems, etc etc. Can you give us some more details of the two machines' setups?

Comment: **craigim:** I ran 'bench' from the command line of both machines: the Linux machine outperformed the Windows machine in every category except 3D. 

**Andrew:** I believe the data is stored on a network drive, but the computer is running the most recent version of MatLab. The Windows machine is a personal computer, while the Linux machine is networked into the server for my lab. I will try storing outputs locally, as you suggest, and get back to  you.

Comment: Apparently replacing 'importdata' with 'dlmread' fixes the problem. No idea why, but 'dlmread' is much faster on Linux. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`importdata` itself is really only a wrapper which calls various other functions - for example, `xlsread` - depending on the type of input data. Since it takes multiple types of file as input (you can even load images with it, although why you would is another matter), it needs to work out what the file is, then call the appropriate function.

`dlmread`, on the other hand, only takes a specific type of file (ASCII-delimited numeric).

**In Short:**
Never use one-size-fits-all functions like `importdata` when you can use more specific functions.  You can see a list of file formats and specific read/write functions [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html).

I don't think this is limited to Linux, either. A thousand repeats, loading of a small tab delimited file on a Windows machine:

`dlmread` : 0.756655 seconds

`csvread` : 1.332842 seconds

`importdata` : 69.508252 seconds